# Filtrar los valores de una tabla segun variables foranea

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Veran, tengo 3 tablas: las plantas, los usuarios y los comentarios. La tabla de comentarios tiene claves foraneas que apuntan a una planta y un usuario determinados.

Con eso en mente, cree una vista la cual muestra los comentarios filtrandolos segun sobre que planta se habla.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora tengo que conseguir 2 cosas. La primera, que en vez del código del usuario muestre su nombre (variable name de la tabla User) y que se muestre un mensaje con el nombre de la planta a la cual vemos sus comentarios.

Para este caso me interesa conseguir lo primero, para lo cual deberia modificar vegetal/detail.blade.php de la siguiente forma:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <h2 class="text-center text-mute"> {{ __("Comentarios acerca del :nombre", ['nombre' => $pla->nombre]) }} </h2>
        @forelse($comentario as $c)
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading panel-heading-forum">
                <h3>
                    Usuario: {{$c->usuario}}
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                {{ $c->comentario }}
            </div>
        </div>
        @empty
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            {{ __("No hay ningún comentario sobre plantas en este momento") }}
        </div>
        @endforelse
        <a href="/flora/public" class="btn btn-info pull-right"> {{ __("Volver a la lista de plantas") }} </a>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Sin embargo, me sale este mensaje de error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaria saber como muestro correctamente el nombre de la planta.
Claramente el error esta en " {{ __("Comentarios acerca del :nombre", ['nombre' => $pla->nombre]) }} ".
Sin esta linea de codigo, se ve correctamente la tabla.

Dejo otros datos a tener en cuenta.
Web.php:

```
Route::get('/comentarios/{pla}', 'PlantasController@show');
```

PlantasController.php:

```
 public function show(Plantas $pla){
    $comentario = $pla->comentarios()->with(['vegetal'])->paginate(2);
    return view('vegetal.detail', compact('plantas','comentario'));
    }
```

app/plantas.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class plantas extends Model{
    protected $table = 'plantas';

    protected $fillable = [
        'nombre', 'descripcion',
    ];

    public function comentarios(){
        return $this->hasMany(Comentario::class,'planta');
    }
}
```

app/Comentario.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comentario extends Model{
    protected $table = 'comentarios';

    protected $fillable = [
        'planta', 'usuario', 'comentario',
    ];

    public function vegetal(){
        return $this->belongsTo(plantas::class, 'planta');
    }

    public function usuario(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'usuario');
    }
}
```

Edito, ya logre que se muestre a la planta sobre la que se hace el comentario. Ahora ire haciendo la 2ª parte, que he subrayado en la imagen adjunta: Por ahora no se muestra el nombre del usuario que hace el comentario, solo su id. Por lo que toca que aparezca el nombre del que escribio cada comentario.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Está pasando el nombre plantas en el `compact` , debería ser quizá  `$plantas->nombre`

Comment: @Dev.Joel Pues sigue apareciendome el error cuando pongo ['nombre' => $plantas->nombre].

Comment: @Dev.Joel aunque lo cierto es que en el compact tengo 2 valores: plantas y comentario. Durante el detail hay un forelse en el que se trata ,a ,a variable comentario, aunque he probado hacer otro para plantas y tambien da error.

Comment: Qué error muestra al cambiar el nombre de `$pla` por `$plantas` ? ¿El mismo?

Comment: @Dev.Joel este es el mensaje de error: Undefined variable: planta (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\flora\resources\views\vegetal\detail.blade.php)

Comment: @Dev.Joel Actualmente tengo la función como "return view('vegetal.detail', compact('planta','comentario'));". Vamos, que esto sigue igual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás intentando usar [Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-model-binding) de forma incorrecta, pues debes darle el nombre a la variable parámetro que corresponda con el nombre del modelo.

Según la documentación lo más correcto sería:

Ruta

```
Route::get('/comentarios/{plantas}', 'PlantasController@show');
```

Controlados

```
public function show(Plantas $plantas)
{
    $comentario = $plantas->comentarios()->with(['vegetal'])->paginate(2);
    return view('vegetal.detail', compact('plantas','comentario'));
}
```

En general y basándome en las preguntas anteriores que has hecho, creo que no has entendido bien aún varios conceptos básicos de Laravel y de PHP, por lo cual te sugeriría que revises con más detalle su documentación.

Comment: Pues gracias, he logrado que se muestre el texto.

Comment: Recuerdo que ahora tocaba sustituir el id del usuario (tabla User) por su nombre (variable name). Voy a ver si puedo hacerlo antes de regresar por aqui.

Comment: No sé a qué te refieres.

Comment: Quisiera mostrartelo con una captura de pantalla, por lo que he editado esta pregunta.